# Gambling and chance

Tags: gambling

I know a video game where you have your own army, and you can send them on missions for example, some volunteers, medicinal plants, or blueprints from the enemy.

Here’s the catch: it also says what your chances are of winning and losing, and usually there are some that are high in chances of winning (95% success probability) and quite low chances of losing (3%, 10% etc)

My question is: would it still be considered gambling if one has an incredibly high chance of winning and knows what the outcome contains?

Comment: Is the 'enemy' another player like you?

Comment: @Crimson no, they are virtual enemies.

Comment: Jazak Allah khayran, I saw your account and it seems that you're careful about doing halal and avoiding haram. Though you may increase in knowledge (by reading Quran and the Sunnah, because both of them are guidance) and make duas that Allah keeps you steadfast in Islam.

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios based upon your question
1) This is not gambling because you're just simulating an action through a simulator (i.e videogame). In the same way you're not stealing because you control a character who's a thief, you're not a gambler for doing that through a simulator

2)You're actually gambling because however you're basing a certain outcome on chance and probability, even if no money is involved (whether virtual or real, but in this case I assume virtual) and furthermore you yourself are enacting and implementing the bet, not the character by itself, and so it may be that the sin would retract towards you. Now in this scenario, if it were a concrete action that happens to be committed by hands then there's no sin upon you, but since the action you are taking on board in this scenario can be considered abstract, then it could be that it is taking place EVEN in this worldly reality because you are "betting" from your points in the videogame, and even if it is not direct as an action, it is still betting because you're committing it from a game-based currency.

Edit: it is unlikely that if you're committing a sin with a character it evolves into a sin against you in the real world, but on the particular case of betting, it MAY BE that you yourself are basing your outcome on percentage and by putting fake currency. Surest thing is not to play at all.

Comment: Hm, alright, thanks for the answer. I also asked a question about gambling in the past, but no one has answered it, so if you have an answer for it, i'd gladly want to hear it. What about those 'lootboxes' in some games? I usually think they are gambling so i stay away from them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a game. It's not gambling. It would be gambling if you were staking something on the outcome of the game. As you are not, it's not.